# How to test that an input string in C is of the correct 'format'?

Tags: c

I've written a simple calculator app in C and it works pretty well so far but I'm missing one thing: how to ensure the user has entered an input in the correct form e.g. "6 + 7". Is there any way I can test for that?

Here is my code so far:

```
/*A simple calculator that can add, subtract and multiple. TODO: Division
and add error handling i.e. if not an expected input!*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char input[10];
  int result;
  printf("Welcome to the calculator! The available operations are +, - and *.\n");
  while (1) {
    printf("What would you like to calculate?\n");
    fgets(input, 10, stdin); /*Getting user input in form e.g. 4 + 7*/

    /*Ideally test for input should go here*/

    /*Separating user input into the numbers and operators, using strtok and
    space as a delimiter*/
    char *firstNumber = strtok(input, " ");
    char *operator = strtok(NULL, " ");
    char *secondNumber = strtok(NULL, " ");

    /*Converting the separated numbers to integers*/
    int firstInt = atoi(firstNumber);
    int secondInt = atoi(secondNumber);

    if (strcmp(operator, "+") == 0) {
      result = firstInt + secondInt;
    } else if (strcmp(operator, "-") == 0) {
      result = firstInt - secondInt;
    } else if (strcmp(operator, "*") == 0) {
      result = firstInt * secondInt;
    } else {
      printf("That ain't a valid operator sonny jim. Try again:\n");
      continue;
    }

    printf("Your result is %d.\n", result);

    int flag = 0;

    while (flag == 0) {
      printf("Would you like to do another calculation? (yes or no)\n");
      fgets(input, 10, stdin);
      if (strcmp(input, "yes\n") == 0) {
        flag = 1;
      } else if (strcmp(input, "no\n") == 0) {
        flag = 2;
      } else {
        printf("That isn't a valid response. Please respond yes or no.\n");
      }
    }
    if (flag == 2) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Well you could use `sscanf` with something like `"%d %c %d"` and check its return value. If it is 3 then it was succesful. Then you only need to check that the operator is a valid one.

Comment: Before deciding to use scanf, you may want to read this though: [A beginner's guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: If you want to be able to evaluate nested expression, you need a proper grammar and a corresponding parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily the best way, but I would use `sscanf` this way:

```
    int firstInt;
    int secondInt;
    char operator;
    if (3 != sscanf(input, "%d %c %d %1[^\n]", &firstInt, &operator, &secondInt, &temp)) {
      printf("Invalid input Billy!\n");
      continue;
    }
```

`sscanf` should return 3 if it successfully read in the values from the input string. If it would return 4 that would mean it read some trailing non whitespace characters which is invalid. The added benefit of this approach is that you don't need to parse the operands elsewhere with `atoi`.

Whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char input[10];
  char temp[2];
  int result;
  printf("Welcome to the calculator! The available operations are +, - and *.\n");
  while (1) {
    printf("What would you like to calculate?\n");
    fgets(input, 10, stdin); /*Getting user input in form e.g. 4 + 7*/

    /*Ideally test for input should go here*/
    int firstInt;
    int secondInt;
    char operator;
    if (3 != sscanf(input, "%d %c %d %1[^\n]", &firstInt, &operator, &secondInt, temp)) {
      printf("Invalid input Billy!\n");
      continue;
    }

    if ('+'== operator) {
      result = firstInt + secondInt;
    } else if ('-' == operator) {
      result = firstInt - secondInt;
    } else if ('*' == operator) {
      result = firstInt * secondInt;
    } else {
      printf("That ain't a valid operator sonny jim. Try again:\n");
      continue;
    }

    printf("Your result is %d.\n", result);

    int flag = 0;

    while (flag == 0) {
      printf("Would you like to do another calculation? (yes or no)\n");
      fgets(input, 10, stdin);
      if (strcmp(input, "yes\n") == 0) {
        flag = 1;
      } else if (strcmp(input, "no\n") == 0) {
        flag = 2;
      } else {
        printf("That isn't a valid response. Please respond yes or no.\n");
      }
    }
    if (flag == 2) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why inverted some conditions are, and in proper order are other conditions? I suggest coherence: make them all inverted or all proper.

Comment: Putting newlines at the end of the scanf format string is pointless and confusing.  If you want to check that you've scanned the entire string, use `%n` -- `sscanf(input, "%d %c%d %n", &first, &op, &second, &len) >= 3 && input[len] == 0`

Comment: `char temp; ... sscanf(input, "%*d %*c %*d%1[^\n]", &temp)` leads to _undefined behavior_ (UB) as `temp` is too small.  Not yet a good job, but easy to fix.  It is unclear why the first `sscanf()` did not incorporate the `1[^\n]` and then tolerate a return value of 3 or 4.

Comment: Well I added the second sscanf later. Then I realized they could be merged to one, but I left as it is. But I merged them since I had to fix the UB you spotted. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

The first test you should do is for length. You only allow input of ten characters. That's one for the operator, two for spaces, one for the `\n`, and one for the `NUL` terminator. That leaves only 5 characters to be split amongst the two operands. So, if the user inputs `543 * 65`, you've already truncated the `\n`. An input of `5432 * 65`, and you start losing important data. The way I would implement a length check is to search for the `\n`:
`if (input[0] && input[strlen(input) - 1] != '\n')`, you know the input has been truncated.<sup>†</sup> Next, you need to check for the validity of the characters. If you keep your `strtok()` method, you can do input checking when you convert the string to an integer if you use the preferred function `strtol()`<sup>††</sup> with far better error checking. As for the operator, you already have checks on that. For formatting of input: ***check for NULL pointers***. If `strtok()` doesn't find a space delimiter, it will return a NULL pointer, which you would then try to read from later in your program.

<sup>†: I personally would make my input character limit larger: at least 25</sup>
<sup>††: `man strtol` for more information</sup>

Comment: Thanks for catching a second error of mine :) Corrected.

Comment: A good compiler will recognize `strlen(input)` used twice  without a change to `input`, so will not make 2 trips down `input`.  Yet a lesser compiler will run down `input` twice.  A simple alternate, and very C like,: `if (input[0] && input[strlen(input) - 1] != '\n')`

Comment: I was not aware any modern compiler wouldn't optimize that out entirely. Personally, I prefer the readability of checking `strlen()` twice over the possible optimization, but edited again.

Answer (score 2):

> string in C is of the correct 'format'?

A simpler approach uses `" %n"` at the end to record  the offset of the scan - if it made it that far.  Akin to [@Chris Dodd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60917491/how-to-test-that-an-input-string-in-c-is-of-the-correct-format/60920444#comment107777000_60917654) comment.

```
int firstNumber;
char operator[2];
int secondNumber;

int n = 0;
sscanf(input, "%d %1[+-] %d %n", &firstNumber, operator, &secondNumber, &n);
//  v---v--------------------  Scan complete?
if (n > 0 && input[n] == '\0') Success();
//           ^--------------^  No extra junk at the end?
else Fail();
```

Detecting if a space exists is tricky.  This answer and `"%d %c %d"` would pass `"5-7".  If  spaces are required about the operator, use

```
"%d%*[ ]%1[+-]*[ ]%d %n"
```

---

Notice the `" "` in `" %n"` allows scanning to be tolerant of a trailing `'\n'`.  Use as desired.